# corrupt EXIF header: maximum directory nesting level reached

Tags: php-5.3, exif

While uploading some images, i get this error:

corrupt EXIF header: maximum directory nesting level reached

I'm trying to avoid the error by checking if response is false, but the error still happens.

```
    $image = @imagecreatefromstring(file_get_contents($_FILES['fileinput']['tmp_name']));
    $exif = @exif_read_data($_FILES['fileinput']['tmp_name'] ,'EXIF' ,0);
    $rotation = 0;
    if($exif !== false) {
        if(!empty($exif['Orientation'])) {
            switch($exif['Orientation']) {
                case 8:
                    $rotation = 90;
                    break;
                case 3:
                    $rotation = 180;
                    break;
                case 6:
                    $rotation = 270;
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
```

I get this error with just a few images. How can i track the error so i can skip header verification on the images that gives me the error?

Answer (score 0):

There seem to be an issue with some EXIF data from some cameras like Fujifilm and some old php version. Check https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=66443

You may need to update php and maybe compile it from the source code.